# Rails 4: Get records which join association record has been deleted

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following models:

```
class Grade
  belongs_to :student
end

class Student
  has_many :grades
end
```

How can I find out which grades have students which have been deleted? In other words, I want to make a query which returns basically what I'm doing in the next line of code

```
Grade.all - Grade.joins(:student)
```

Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this query:

```
Grade.includes(:student).references(:student).where('students.id IS NULL')
```

This seems very cumbersome from a data integrity perspective though. Either `grades.student_id` should be nullified when a student is deleted, or it should be deleted altogether.

This can be managed easily by setting foreign keys constraints in your database. A nifty gem for this is [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner). Foreign keys will also be part of the [upcoming Rails 4.2 release](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support).

If grades should still continue to exist even though a student is deleted, you can set a foreign key which sets `grades.student_id` for that student to `NULL`:

```
# Foreigner
add_foreign_key :grades, :students, dependent: :nullify

# Rails 4.2
add_foreign_key :grades, :students, on_delete: :nullify
```

You don't need to do anything special for this, the database will take care of cleaning up. If you then want to find grades without students, you can simply run this query:

```
Grade.where(student: nil)
```

If grades should be deleted when a student is being deleted, you can add this foreign key:

```
# Foreigner
add_foreign_key :grades, :students, dependent: :delete

# Rails 4.2
add_foreign_key :grades, :students, on_delete: :cascade
```

Comment: Your query worked, thanks! I am aware of the `dependent` option, and I use it wherever it's appropriate. However, I forgot to do so in one case, so I asked the question :)

Comment: You're welcome! ActiveRecord's `dependent` option works slightly different than the approach I posted though. Foreign keys are managed by the database itself and they also work when calling `student.delete`. The ActiveRecord approach only works when calling `student.destroy` ;)